# Filter/Update Python Dataframe by Data Type

Tags: python, pandas

I'm in the midst of trying to parse CSV files for input to a SQL database and am having just a bit of trouble trying to manipulate a data frame to account for various data types.

I have dataframe that has columns like so:

```
 Date, ID, DataLabel, Value
```

The column for "Value" contains both numeric data and text data. I basically want to create 2 new columns in the data frame called `Value_Num` and `Value_Text`. For those values in the Value column that are numeric, I'd like to copy them into the new `Value_Num` column leaving `Value_Text` null, for those that are text I'd like to copy them into the `Value_Text` column leaving `Value_Num` null.

I would then like to delete the old Value column.

Comment: Can you give some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

# create dummy df for this example
df=pd.DataFrame(['text','1234']*4, columns=['Value'])

df
Value
0  text
1  1234
2  text
3  1234
4  text
5  1234
6  text
7  1234

# convert the numbers first
df['Val_Num']=df.Value.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

# then use the null values in the Val_Num column to find the text values
df['Val_Text']=df.Value.ix[df.Val_Num.isnull()]

# delete the Value column
df.drop('Value', inplace=True, axis=1)

df
Val_Num Val_Text
0      NaN     text
1     1234      NaN
2      NaN     text
3     1234      NaN
4      NaN     text
5     1234      NaN
6      NaN     text
7     1234      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using apply to go through row by row and test whether the value is numeric of string is the quickest way separate them.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-01-01', 1, 'One', 1], ['2015-01-02', 2, 'Two', 'Two']], columns=['Date', 'ID', 'DataLabel', 'Value'])
df['Value_Num'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: x if np.isreal(x) else np.nan)
df['Value_Text'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, str) else np.nan)
df = df.drop('Value', axis=1)
```